# DirectoryEntry failed to get FullName when calling from client

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have this function below:

```
public string GetADDisplayName(string strLogin)
{
    int length = strLogin.IndexOf('\\');
    if (length == -1)
        length = strLogin.IndexOf('@');
    string str1;
    string str2;
    if (length != -1)
    {
        str1 = strLogin.Substring(0, length);
        str2 = strLogin.Substring(length + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        str1 = Environment.MachineName;
        str2 = strLogin;
    }
    string str3;
    try
    {
        str3 = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + str1 + "/" + str2).Properties["FullName"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "", "alert('GetADDisplayName ERROR: " + ex.ToString() + "');", true);
        str3 = "";
    }
    return str3;
}
```

The value I pass into the function is `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Trim()`.

When I debug/F5 in my visual studio, it show me the FullName.

When I deploy to web server and access it from within the web server itself, it show me the FullName.

But when I access the web server from client, it failed to show me the FullName, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach :

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

using (var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext))
    {
        userPrincipal.SamAccountName = 'userdomain name'; // -> ex. jtabuloc

        using (var principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher())
        {
            principalSearcher.QueryFilter = userPrincipal;

            var principal = principalSearcher.FindOne();

            if (principal != null)
            {
                var directoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)principal.GetUnderlyingObject();

                 // You can examine directoryEntry if key exist and retrieve values                   
                 var Name = directoryEntry["name"][0] as string;
                 var FullName = directoryEntry["FullName"][0] as string;
                 var Email = directoryEntry["mail"][0] as string;
                 var Title = directoryEntry["title"][0] as string;
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This could could be simplified more. Since you're searching for a single user by `SamAccountName` you don't really need to use `PrincipalSearcher`. You can combine lines 5-9 into one. `using (UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username)` Also, if the values of any directory objects are null your code will fail. Before grabbing the value of any fields, you need to check if it has value.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting `FullName` using `AccountManagement`:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;
String name = userPrincipal.DisplayName;
```

Comment: Error when access from web server via client. `Exception Details: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations error occurred.`

Comment: No error if I access it from within the web server.

Comment: `Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

Comment: [DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.
]
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +377678
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +36
   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +31
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +26
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry entry, String propertyName) +49
   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String propertyName) +150

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer() +1114
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit() +37
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize() +112
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx() +31
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate) +14

Comment: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue) +86
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue) +31
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current() +216
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +31
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14

Comment: System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

Comment: @Pop dude ..what is this, can you not just edit to your Question.

Comment: I think I cannot edit question after answer was offer.